# How to Compare two strings using a if in a stored procedure in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008, string-comparison

I want to do something like this:

```
declare @temp as varchar
    set @temp='Measure'

if(@temp == 'Measure')
   Select Measure from Measuretable
else
   Select OtherMeasure from Measuretable
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Two things:

1. Only need one (1) equals sign to evaluate
2. You **need** to specify a length on the VARCHAR - the default is a single character.

---

Use:

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR(10)
    SET @temp = 'm'

IF @temp = 'm'
  SELECT 'yes'
ELSE
  SELECT 'no'
```

`VARCHAR(10)` means the VARCHAR will accommodate up to 10 characters.  More examples of the behavior -

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR
    SET @temp = 'm'

IF @temp = 'm'
  SELECT 'yes'
ELSE
  SELECT 'no'
```

...will return "yes"

```
DECLARE @temp VARCHAR
    SET @temp = 'mtest'

IF @temp = 'm'
  SELECT 'yes'
ELSE
  SELECT 'no'
```

...will return "no".

Answer (score 2):

You can also try this for match string.

```
DECLARE @temp1 VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @temp1 = '<li>Error in connecting server.</li>'
DECLARE @temp2 VARCHAR(1000)
    SET @temp2 = '<li>Error in connecting server. connection timeout.</li>'

IF @temp1 like '%Error in connecting server.%' OR @temp1 like '%Error in connecting server. connection timeout.%'
  SELECT 'yes'
ELSE
  SELECT 'no'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
declare @temp as varchar
  set @temp='Measure'
  if(@temp = 'Measure')
Select Measure from Measuretable
else
Select OtherMeasure from Measuretable
```

Comment: @VJ: That's because `@temp VARCHAR` means that @temp will only store the first character; the rest is truncated without error.

Comment: @VJ introduce a parameter, do not set value to temp

Answer (score 1):

What you want is a SQL case statement.
The form of these is either:

```
  select case [expression or column]
  when [value] then [result]
  when [value2] then [result2]
  else [value3] end
```

or:

```
  select case 
  when [expression or column] = [value] then [result]
  when [expression or column] = [value2] then [result2]
  else [value3] end
```

In your example you are after:

```
declare @temp as varchar(100)
set @temp='Measure'

select case @temp 
   when 'Measure' then Measure 
   else OtherMeasure end
from Measuretable
```